# If $f$ is holomorphic there is a holomorphic $H$ such that $\frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)} + H(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, analytic-combinatorics

I am having trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function and suppose that there is a point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and a real $R > \lvert z_0 \rvert$ such that
>
> - $f(z_0) = 0$
> - $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z \ne z_0$ with $\lvert z \rvert < R$
> - $f^\prime(z_0) \ne 0$
>
> Show that there exists a function $H(z)$ that is holomorphic on the open disc of radius $R$ around the origin and satisfies
>
> $$\frac{1}{f(z)} = \frac{1}{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)} + H(z)$$

All I understand from the statement is that $z_0$ is an isolated singularity, but I do not see at all how to derive said identity for $1/f(z)$. Could you please help me?

Thanks to Conrads's Comment here is the solution: Using the Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $z_0$ we have

\begin{equation}
H(z) := \frac{1}{f(z)} - \frac{1}{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)}
= \frac{1}{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)+(z-z_0)^2G(z)} - \frac{1}{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)}
\end{equation}

where $G(z) = \sum_{n \ge 2} f^{(n)}(z) (z-z_0)^{n-2}$ and this is combination of holomorphic functions and thus holomorphic.

Comment: use that $f(z)=f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)+(z-z_0)^2G(z)$ and compute $\frac{1}{f(z)} - \frac{1}{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)}$ to show that it is holomorphic on $|z|<R$

Comment: @Conrad: Thanks for your comment. However, I do not quite get it: I understand that you are using the Taylor series of $f$ around $z_0$, but I do not get where the term $(z-z_0)^2G(z)$ is coming from and what $G(z)$ means exactly. Could you please explain this?

Comment: The Taylor series  $f(z)=f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)+\sum_{n \ge 2}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ gives $G$ by grouping the terms with power at least $2$ together, so $G(z)=\sum_{n \ge 2}a_n(z-z_0)^{n-2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I made an edit with the full argument, to make sure I understand it. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: I would also simplify the result (bring same denominator) and get that $H(z)=\frac{-G(z)}{f'(z_0)(f'(z_0)+(z-z_0)G(z))}$ which shows clearly that the denominator doesn't vanish near $z_0$ and then $H$ which is well defined on the punctured disc $D(z_0,R)^*$ by hypothesis extends to the full disc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If you want you can just copy that and turn it into an answer.